# using colab TPU without GCS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

Simple question.
I would like to use the TPU in google colab. All tutorials, I have seen suggested using a GCS bucket in order to use a custom dataset.
My question is now, do I have to use googles service or can I use AWS.
Is there any workaround to use the disk of the colab instance?

In case you need to know, I am using TensorFlow 2 with python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently there's no way your TPU can use an AWS bucket as it's filesystem. You'll need to use GCS, as TPUs only have GCS filesystem registered.